# Automatically change order status to paid upon successful payment

Tags: magento

I'm using payment gateway - secure ebs in magento..
When an order is placed new order status is set to - processing 
Then in order details.. in order comments section it says:
1. Processing - Customer Notified
2. Processing - Customer was redirected to Secureebs
3. Processing - Customer successfully returned from Secureebs

I want to have different status in 3rd case.. for e.g. In 3rd case I want that status automatically changes to Paid from Processing.

Another question is that is it possible to manually set Statuses.. once its paid.. 
So I can create a wrokflow for my different teams and tell them to listen on their particular status. So they can just keep on checking the orders which are lying with status they are the owner of. In comments section there's a dropdown but it doesnot show all statuses.

Answer (score 0):

"So I can create a wrokflow for my different teams and tell them to listen on their particular status. So they can just keep on checking the orders which are lying with status they are the owner of." - This really doesn't make much sense.

And you should NOT change order status manually.

Comment: Basically I want to instruct my team to filter the orders page with their specific status(as in the status upon which they are supposed to take action)

And another problem is that right now all my orders are coming as status- processing in both cases( CaseI- customer redirected to gateway but not returned, CaseII- Customer returned succesfully from gateway) In second case I want to that the status should be paid